# Visualising 'The Moessner Miracle' in higher dimensions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics3d

I thought it would be interesting to try and represent "The Moessner Miracle" in higher dimensions. This is my first attempt for higher dimensions anywhere so I'm not sure if the logic is correct.

The principles are explained nicely [here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=rGlpyFHfMgI)

The 3D case

```
Table[1, 15]
Accumulate[%]
Accumulate[Drop[%, {3, Length[%], 3}]]
```

```
out[]: 
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
{1,3,7,12,19,27,37,48,61,75}
```

We can visualise using:

[image]

```
ListAnimate[
 Show[{{Graphics3D[Cuboid[#]] & /@ Tuples[Range[0, #], 3]}}] & /@ 
  Range[5]]
```

The 4D case

The individual cubes don't seem to behave as the 3D, each being made of increasing number of cubes

[image]

```
ListAnimate[Show[{
     {Graphics3D[
         Cuboid[#]] & /@ (Map[# + {#[[-1]], #[[-1]], #[[-1]], 0} &, 
           Tuples[Range[0, #], 4], {1}][[All, ;; 3]]*2 #)}
     }] & /@ Range[5]]
```

The 5D case

I'm not sure if I can change tact in higher dimensions, although for the 5th, I hoped to have an increasing speed with the cubes orbiting their original position

Made this mess:

[image]

I thought maybe it could rotate with increasing speed, couldn't figure it out

[image]

***Warning can take a while to run:***

```
ListAnimate[Show[{
     {Graphics3D[
         GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[#], 
          RotationTransform[ 
           Pi/Length[Tuples[Range[0, 1], 4]], {1, 1, 
            1}]]] & /@ (Map[# + {#[[-1]], #[[-1]], #[[-1]], 0} &, 
           Tuples[Range[0, #], 4], {1}][[All, ;; 3]]*2 #)}
     }] & /@ Range[5]]
```

---

***Update***

3D -> 4D -> 5D (ish)

It's a little hard to see & the speed doesn't change with the 5D pattern.
Reaching the limit of my PC, thought it would be interesting if with the 4D distribution there was some form of ripple pattern as the speed increases and cubes multiply

[image]

```
(*Accumulate[Drop[%,{5,Length[%],5}]] *)
Accumulate[Drop[%, {4, Length[%], 4}]] 
Accumulate[Drop[%, {3, Length[%], 3}]]
a0 = Accumulate[Drop[%, {2, Length[%], 2}]]
```

```
i0=Append[1]/@CirclePoints[x0[[1,1,;;2]],2,50]//N;

Table[Show[Table[{Graphics3D[Cuboid[(#+n)*i0[[i]]],Boxed->False]&/@Tuples[Range[0,#],3]},{n,1,2*a0[[#]],5}]]&/@{1,2,3},{i,Length[i0]}];
Transpose@%;
d5=Join[%[[1]],%[[2]],%[[3]]];
```

Comment: Very nice video; it made my day! Thank you very much! (+1)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher "Very nice, very nice, very nice" (in a German accent)